# Is there a way to filter DataTable by distinct entries?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a datatable that has x amount of unique entries in column A. I want to be able to use `DataTable.Select()` to get each name in column A once. I couldn't seem to find any type of SQL equivalent of `Distinct` in the microsoft docs. Any help would be appreciated.

I have a DataTable that has 6 columns. I want to pull each unique entry in column 1 and store the row like this 
`DataRow[] rows = DataTable.Select("expression here");`
I then want to iterate through each row and set the values to an x-axis on a chart. Like so...

```
for(int i = 0; i < rows.Length; i++)
{
    string id = rows[i]["USER_ID"].ToString();
}
```

Comment: there is groupBy

Comment: AsEnumerable and Distinct come to mind. Need more code to tell what you're doing and what you have available to use.

Comment: I have added some more details, let me know if it makes more sense

Comment: If Column A has unique entries, why do you need to do *anything* to get distinct values?

Comment: Sorry I suppose that was worded badly. For example say there is 25 rows there may only be 8 unique entries and I want to only pull each unique entry once.

Comment: dt.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.Field<string>("USER_ID")).Distinct().ToArraqy();

Comment: If you put that as an answer @jdweng I will mark it as correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a typo in @jdweng's comment. The correct answer should be:

```cs
dataTable.AsEnumerable().Select(row => row["USER_ID"]).Distinct().ToArray();
```